# Identify the cause of BSOD from a minidump file

Tags: windows-7, bsod, minidumps

I have the following information in the Windows minidump file:

```
Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  python.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`009f7b58 fffff800`035faa3b : 00000000`00000124 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`072a7028 00000000`bf800000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`009f7b60 fffff800`0318bd5f : 00000000`00000001 fffffa80`06d2e8e0 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`06d2e930 : hal!HalBugCheckSystem+0x1e3
fffff880`009f7ba0 fffff800`035fa700 : 00000000`00000728 fffffa80`06d2e8e0 fffff880`009f7f30 fffff880`009f7f00 : nt!WheaReportHwError+0x26f
fffff880`009f7c00 fffff800`035fa052 : fffffa80`06d2e8e0 fffff880`009f7f30 fffffa80`06d2e8e0 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMcaReportError+0x4c
fffff880`009f7d50 fffff800`035f9f0d : 00000000`00000008 00000000`00000001 fffff880`009f7fb0 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandler+0x9e
fffff880`009f7d90 fffff800`035ede88 : 00000000`003aaaf8 00000000`003a70e0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous+0x55
fffff880`009f7dc0 fffff800`0306fd2c : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalHandleMcheck+0x40
fffff880`009f7df0 fffff800`0306fb93 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxMcheckAbort+0x6c
fffff880`009f7f30 00000000`170f6b44 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiMcheckAbort+0x153
00000000`003a7000 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x170f6b44


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: GenuineIntel

IMAGE_NAME:  GenuineIntel

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

I am not very familiar with these type files. Could someone please tell me what is the problem?

Is it something critical with the processor, or something that is possible to fix?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use windbg to analyze the dump. There are numerous answers here at SU that go into detail.  However, it appears Python is to blame, typically windbg is used when a driver the suspect cause.  Wish I could provide more but what you have provided can’t be used to diagnose the problem it.  Only you have the file itself, research the subject, it’s not a difficult task

Comment: check my answer from the duplicate. it shows how to debug the issue. you also have a CPU hw issue